# Wireguard - single server with multiple interfaces

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have one raspberry, and there I have ethernet connection to internet `eth0` and I have another wireless connection `wlan0` that is also conneted to internet via other router.

Is it possible to create `wg0` to be wireguard for `eth0` (so that clients that connect there are always only forwarded via eth0), and `wg1` to be wireguard for `wlan0` (so that clients connected there are always forwarded via wlan0)?

Comment: See `iif` of `ip rule`.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a quick browse of their documentation and it seems this is possible by using the `via` keyword when adding the routes.

You can see the specifics in "The Classic Solutions" section of their docs.
https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#the-classic-solutions

Comment: Some small example ;)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).